# How to Get UIImagePickerController as First screen in TabBarApplication

Tags: iphone

How to open Photo Library in First screen as pushviewcontroller in tabBarApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent view controller, and in viewDidLoad for that controller:

```
[self pushViewController:photosViewController animated:NO].
```

By the time the view is displayed, the photo library view controller will be frontmost.